# HealthKit data types overview

Tags: ios, healthkit

What are the various data types tracked by [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/) in iOS?

I've not found any good overview and lists of the data types offered by HealthKit in iOS 8 & 9.

I've gleaned this list from various sources including the WWDC videos of [2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#203) and [2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=203). But I'm looking for a more thorough list & discussion. I've not found it in the developer.apple.com site.

## iOS 8

**Characteristics:**

- Birth date
- Blood type
- Biological sex.

**Basic Samples:**

- Height
- Weight
- Body fat %
- BMI (body mass index)
- Blood pressure
- Oxygen Saturation
- Blood Alcohol Content (BAC)
- Blood Glucose
- Respiratory Rate
- Spirometry
- Heart rate

**Sleep Samples:**
??

**Food Samples:**

- Calories
- Vitamins (A, C, B6, B12)
- Minerals (Potassium)

**Exercise Samples:**

- Steps
- Flights climbed
- “Nike Fuel” ([Nike site](http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/nikeplus/nikefuel))
- Inhaler Usage
- Cycling distance

## iOS 9

iOS 9 adds the following types.

**Characteristics:**

- Fitzpatrick Skin Type.
  Skin tone on a range from I to VI. A way to classify the typical response of different types of skin to ultraviolet (UV) light.
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzpatrick_scale

**Samples:**

- UV exposure. (UV index, 0-12)
- Water intake.

**Reproductive Samples:**

- Basal body temp
- Cervical mucus quality (values: Dry, Sticky, Creamy, Watery, EggWhite).
- Ovulation Test Result (for [LH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luteinizing_hormone) surge) (values: Negative, Positive)
- Menstruation start
- Menstrual flow (values: Unspecified, Light, Medium, Heavy)
- Vaginal spotting (outside of menstruation)
- Sexual activity (a Boolean)

  - Protected vs. unprotected state, both in terms of STIs and protection against pregnancy.

Answer (score 16):

Found in Xcode by command clicking on one of the HKQuantityTypeIdentifiers in my code (eg HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex). This is a list of all measurement types HealthKit can store and in the brackets on the end of each line is the iOS version it is available from.

```
/*--------------------------------*/
/*   HKQuantityType Identifiers   */
/*--------------------------------*/

// Body Measurements
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Scalar(Count),               Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyFatPercentage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // Scalar(Percent, 0.0 - 1.0),  Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                    // Length,                      Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                  // Mass,                        Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierLeanBodyMass NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);              // Mass,                        Discrete

// Fitness
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                 // Scalar(Count),               Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);    // Length,                      Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Length,                      Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBasalEnergyBurned NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // Energy,                      Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);        // Energy,                      Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);            // Scalar(Count),               Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierNikeFuel NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                  // Scalar(Count),               Cumulative

// Vitals
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);                 // Scalar(Count)/Time,          Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyTemperature NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Temperature,                 Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBasalBodyTemperature NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);      // Basal Body Temperature,      Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureSystolic NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);     // Pressure,                    Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureDiastolic NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);    // Pressure,                    Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierRespiratoryRate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Scalar(Count)/Time,          Discrete

// Results
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierOxygenSaturation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);          // Scalar (Percent, 0.0 - 1.0,  Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierPeripheralPerfusionIndex NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);  // Scalar(Percent, 0.0 - 1.0),  Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);              // Mass/Volume,                 Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierNumberOfTimesFallen NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // Scalar(Count),               Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierElectrodermalActivity NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);     // Conductance,                 Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierInhalerUsage NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);              // Scalar(Count),               Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodAlcoholContent NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // Scalar(Percent, 0.0 - 1.0),  Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierForcedVitalCapacity NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // Volume,                      Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierForcedExpiratoryVolume1 NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);   // Volume,                      Discrete
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierPeakExpiratoryFlowRate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);    // Volume/Time,                 Discrete

// Nutrition
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFatTotal NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFatPolyunsaturated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0); // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFatMonounsaturated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0); // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFatSaturated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);       // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCholesterol NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);        // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietarySodium NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCarbohydrates NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);      // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFiber NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);              // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietarySugar NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);              // Mass,   Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);     // Energy, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryProtein NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);            // Mass,   Cumulative

HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminA NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminB6 NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);          // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminB12 NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminC NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminD NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminE NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryVitaminK NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCalcium NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);            // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryIron NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);               // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryThiamin NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);            // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryRiboflavin NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryNiacin NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryFolate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryBiotin NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryPantothenicAcid NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);    // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryPhosphorus NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryIodine NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryMagnesium NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);          // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryZinc NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);               // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietarySelenium NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCopper NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryManganese NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);          // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryChromium NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryMolybdenum NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);         // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryChloride NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryPotassium NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);          // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryCaffeine NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);           // Mass, Cumulative
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryWater NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);              // Volume, Cumulative

HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKQuantityTypeIdentifierUVExposure NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);                // Scalar (Count), Discrete

/*--------------------------------*/
/*   HKCategoryType Identifiers   */
/*--------------------------------*/

HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);             // HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSedentaryState NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);            // HKCategoryValueSedentaryState
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierCervicalMucusQuality NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);      // HKCategoryValueCervicalMucusQuality
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierOvulationTestResult NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);       // HKCategoryValueOvulationTestResult
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierMenstrualFlow NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);             // HKCategoryValueMenstrualFlow
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierVaginalSpotting NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);           // HKCategoryValue
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSexualActivity NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);            // HKCategoryValue


/*--------------------------------------*/
/*   HKCharacteristicType Identifiers   */
/*--------------------------------------*/

HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0); // NSNumber (HKCharacteristicBiologicalSex)
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);     // NSNumber (HKCharacteristicBloodType)
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);   // NSDate
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0); // HKFitzpatrickSkinType

/*-----------------------------------*/
/*   HKCorrelationType Identifiers   */
/*-----------------------------------*/

HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierBloodPressure NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKCorrelationTypeIdentifierFood NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);

/*------------------------------*/
/*   HKWorkoutType Identifier   */
/*------------------------------*/

HK_EXTERN NSString * const HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

Answer (score 5):

[HealthKit Constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Constants/index.html) covers the data types you can fetch, but doesn't seem to have the iOS9 additions yet.

Answer (score 3):

**How is data categorize?**

- Samples
- *Characteristic* -
  This data includes the user’s birthdate,
  blood type, biological sex, and skin type This information can only
  be edited by user only thru the apple Health App

**Sample info?**

- UUID
- Metadata
- Source
- Revision
- Device
- Type
- Start Date
- End Date

**Types of Sample Data?**

- *Category Sample* :
  The way sample data can be classified into finite sets
- *Quantity Sample* :
  Data stored with numerical values like  steps, users weight, pulse rate
- *Correlations* :
  representations of food and blood pressure data
- *Workouts* :
  physical activities like swimming, jogging
  additional properties like 
  type of workout
  duration of workout
  distance
  energy burned

***Examples of Data:***

**Body Measurements:**

- Body Fat Percentage
- Body Mass Index
- Height
- Lean Body Mass
- Weight

**Fitness:**

- active energy
- Activity
- Cycling distance
- exercise minutes
- flights climbed
- nikefuel
- resting hours
- stand hours
- steps
- waking+running distance
- workouts

**Nutritio**n

- Calcium
- Copper,
- etc

**Reproductive Health:**

- Basal Body Temperature
- Cervical Mucus Quality
- menstruation
- ovulation test results
- sexual activity
- spotting

**Results:**

- Blood Glucose
- inhaler usage
- oxygen saturation
- UV Index
- Blood Alcohol content
- and more

**Sleep Analysis:**

- In bed /asleep

**Vitals:**

- Blood pressure
- body temperature
- heart rate
- respiratory rates

Answer (score 3):

The data types used by [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/health-fitness/) are listed on the [HealthKit Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/data_types) page, [HKObjectType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobjecttype) overview and [Workouts and Activity Rings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings) topics. (Page search `TypeIdentifier`)

- [HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcharacteristictypeidentifier): Data which does not typically change e.g. birthday, blood type.
- [HKQuantityTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytypeidentifier): Numerical values e.g. activity duration, body measurement, lab result quantity, nutrition consumed.
- [HKCategoryTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcategorytypeidentifier): Sample type categories e.g. audio exposure, heart rate event, sleep analysis, etc.
- [HKCorrelationTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkcorrelationtypeidentifier): Complex samples e.g. blood pressure, food.
- [HKDocumentTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkdocumenttypeidentifier): Clinical Document Architecture (CDA) identifier.
- [HKClinicalTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkclinicaltypeidentifier): Specialized records e.g. immunization record, lab result record.
- [HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkouttypeidentifier), [HKWorkoutRouteTypeIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutroutetypeidentifier)